# How to save spinner state for specific item

Tags: android, spinner

So I have an android app that organises a list of items. Each item has the same fields. Including one selected by way of spinner.
 I can save the details of each item individually just fine, and open them and edit them without any problem.
However, when ever I change the spinner value on one item, it changes it for all of them. How can I set the position of the spinner, for each individual item? The code below shows how I create the spinner, and save it's state. The problem is it's state is saved for all items in the list. How can I save it individually?

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, genres);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    //SET SELECTION AFTER YOU SET THE ADAPTER NOT BEFORE IT
    spinner.setSelection(preferences.getInt("spinnerSelection",0));
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        SharedPreferences preferences =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MovieInfo.this);

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
            int item = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

            //String selected = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            //Toast.makeText(MovieInfo.this, "Selected item: " + selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("spinnerSelection", item);
            editor.commit();

        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

         }
    });
```

Comment: No clear what you want. Show us piece of code, expected output etc, so that others can be clear on exact thing you want

Comment: So the problem is you want to save using distinct __KEY__? Other than __spinnerSelection__ ?

Comment: Yes, something that allows the value to be set for each item.

Comment: Can you tell me the scenario for use? I cannot understand exactly what you want.

Do you want to check if each item is selected?

Comment: Sorry if i'm being vague, I didn't think the scenario was important. Anyway, the app organises a list of movies, each movie has a genre attribute that is selected by the spinner. I want each movie to save the genre selected in the spinner. Right now the genre is set for every movie, because they all use the same spinner from the activity that creates a new movie.

Comment: Use database. Not SharedPreferences

Comment: So, where do I update the database field. in the onItemSelected?

Comment: yes. Do the necessary work inside the onItemSelected() method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76686/discussion-between-q-ali-and-nabin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you can accomplish this using **SharedPreferences**, I would recommend you to use **database instead**.

Add the related code inside the **onItemSelected()** method. May be you want to add the record in sqlite inside the method.

**Update:**

As per you question in chat, you can use **Field** variable instead of **local** to remove the need to make it **final**.